# Spot the Ruby syntax error: NameError: undefined local variable or method ` '

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.0

Here are two lines of Ruby that checks how many of the items in an array are "valid" or "invalid":

```
valid = cr.select { |x| x.valid? }.count
invalid = cr.select { |x| !x.valid? }.count
```

Can anybody spot why the second line has a syntax error? I have stepped through this code in a debugger, and the exception is raised when it tries to execute the `invalid = ...` line. The only difference between the two lines is the `!`, and I have checked that `!true == false` works. I'm stumped.

---

This is the entire code file:

```
require "colored"

require "address_kit/cli/interactive/command"
require "address_kit/cli/interactive/shell"

module AddressKit
  module CLI
    module Interactive
      module Commands

        class TableValidationStats < TableCommand
          NAME = "table_validation_stats"
          SUMMARY = "Displays statistics about the table address validation"
          HELP_TEXT = <<-TEXT.chomp.reset_indentation
            This command displays how many rows that has been validated, how
            many of those rows were valid, invalid or auto-corrected.
          TEXT

          def execute(context, args)
            super

            shell = context.shell
            results = context.vars[:address_processing_results] || []

            if results.length < 1
              shell.puts_padded "No rows have been processed"
              return
            end

            require "byebug"; byebug

            cr = results.compact
            total_processed = cr.count
            failed_parsing = cr.select { |x| !x.parsed? }.count
            valid = cr.select { |x| x.valid? }.count
            invalid = cr.select { |x| !x.valid? }.count
            corrected = cr.select { |x| x.corrected? }.count

            shell.puts
            shell.puts "Rows processed: #{total_processed.to_s.bold}"
            shell.puts "Parse failures: #{failed_parsing.to_s.bold}"
            shell.puts "Valid addresses: #{valid.to_s.bold}"
            shell.puts "Invalid addresses: #{invalid.to_s.bold}"
            shell.puts "Addresses auto-corrected: #{corrected.to_s.bold}"
            shell.puts
          end
        end

        Shell.register_command TableValidationStats

      end
    end
  end
end
```

This is the error with stack trace (ignore the extra text, my project prints error info manually):

```
  AN ERROR HAS OCCURRED!

  The command you just ran produced an unexpected error.
  Your shell session will not be lost, but please report
  the following text to the maintainer of this project:

  Exception: NameError
  Message: undefined local variable or method ` ' for #<AddressKit::CLI::Interactive::Commands::TableValidationStats:0x00000001a6b840>

  Stack trace:
  /home/tomas/Dropbox/Kvantel/Address Kit/lib/address_kit/cli/interactive/commands/table_validation_stats.rb:37:in `block in execute'
  /home/tomas/Dropbox/Kvantel/Address Kit/lib/address_kit/cli/interactive/commands/table_validation_stats.rb:37:in `select'
  /home/tomas/Dropbox/Kvantel/Address Kit/lib/address_kit/cli/interactive/commands/table_validation_stats.rb:37:in `execute'
  /home/tomas/Dropbox/Kvantel/Address Kit/lib/address_kit/cli/interactive/shell.rb:82:in `shell_iteration'
  /home/tomas/Dropbox/Kvantel/Address Kit/lib/address_kit/cli/interactive/shell.rb:46:in `start'
  bin/address_kit_shell:42:in `<main>'
```

And the variable `cr` is an array of `AddressProcessingResult` objects. They look like this:

```
module AddressKit

  # This class represents the end result of the processing of an address,
  # including normalization, parsing, validation and correction.
  class AddressProcessingResult
    attr_accessor :original_address, :parsed_address, :corrected_address, :note
    attr_writer :parsed, :validated, :valid, :corrected

    def initialize(original_address = nil)
      @original_address = original_address
      @parsed_address = nil
      @corrected_address = nil
      @note = ""
      @parsed = false
      @validated = false
      @valid = false
      @corrected = false
    end

    def parsed?; @parsed; end
    def validated?; @validated; end
    def valid?; @valid; end
    def corrected?; @corrected; end

    def readable_summary
      if not parsed?
        "Failed to parse address: #{@original_address}"
      elsif valid?
        "Address is valid: #{@parsed_address}"
      elsif corrected?
        "Address was auto-corrected: #{@corrected_address}: #{@note}"
      else
        "Address was invalid and could not be corrected: #{@corrected_address}"
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: show us the error..please

Comment: @Priti: That was stupid of me. I assumed this was a simple and easily spottable syntax error, so I didn't bother to include anything else. I edited the question now.

Comment: what line is here `bin/address_kit_shell:42:in `<main>'`?

Comment: What happens if you delete the line `invalid = ...`, does the code then work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you perhaps have a Unicode space character in your code (as the result of a copy-paste from elsewhere)? Ruby will interpret that as a valid variable name! Proof:

```
script = <<-EOF
  #{"\u00A0"} = "foo"
  puts #{"\u00A0"}
EOF

puts "The contents of the script are:"
puts script

puts "The output of the script is:"
eval script
```

And output:

```
The contents of the script are:
    = "foo"
  puts  
The output of the script is:
foo
```

I'd use a hex editor or some other scrubber to check for unicode characters in your source code. I can produce the same error message like so:

```
> eval "puts #{"\u00A0"}"
NameError: undefined local variable or method ` ' for main:Object
```

You can scan a file for non-ASCII characters like so:

```
def find_nonascii(file)
  p_line = 1; p_char = 0
  open(file, "r").each_char do |char|
    if char.ord == 10
      p_line += 1
      p_char = 0
    end
    p_char += 1
    puts "Found character #{char.ord} (#{char.inspect}) at line #{p_line}, character #{p_char}" if char.ord > 126
  end
end
```

This will give you the position of the first non-ascii character in the script.

You can find a list of Unicode space characters [here](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html).

Comment: Why do you assume that the end of line is going to be a `\r` character? (`13.chr == "\r"`)

Comment: Brainfart. Should be 10 :-)

Comment: I can only assume this answer is correct. I erased and retyped every space character in the erroneous line and two lines above and below, and now it works without issue. I never pasted anything though, so I must have somehow created a weird white space character by some accidental key combination. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: option-space will give you a Unicode NBSP if you're on a Mac. That's probably what happened; might be a good idea to see if you can configure your editor to guard against that!

Comment: @ChrisHeald: Update: Turns out my keyboard indeed produces non-breaking space characters upon AltGr+Space. I managed to map the NBSP character to produce a normal space character in Vim, so the problem is largely gone.